# Silverlight Crashes in Safari/Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome

Silverlight crashes in Chrome with the error "Silverlight Plug-In has crashed." and in Safari/Webkit nightly build with "Plugin Failure" but works fine with Firefox.

I've verified that both Chrome and Safari are up to date, as well as Silverlight itself.

I had read some other message board posts about this issue possibly being linked to Mac Pro or the video cards used, but no solution is ever provided.

Comment: Note, manually removing `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.pkg` and reinstalling produces the same result.

Comment: What is your Mac model? A Mac Pro? In that case, can you provide the link to the message board you mention?

Comment: I can't for the life of me find the thread with that info, but yes, It's a Mac Pro 5,1 (2x ATI Radeon 5770s).